# How to train a cnn with two classes with different frequency?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am training a simple Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) which should perform a binary classification. The package I am using is keras.
What I need is my training set to be unbalanced. For example, one of the classes should be trained with 900 images, and the other one with only 300 images.

The code I am using is the following:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense

classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3),
                      input_shape=(64, 64, 3),
                      activation='relu'))

classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam',
                   loss='binary_crossentropy',
                   metrics=['accuracy'])

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size=(64, 64),
                                                 batch_size=32,
                                                 class_mode='binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size=(64, 64),
                                            batch_size=32,
                                            class_mode='binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch=1200,
                         epochs=30,
                         validation_data=test_set,
                         validation_steps=50)
```

Right now the model is being trained with a batch_size of 32.
I am guessing that this means that it takes 16 training examples from one of the classes and 16 from the other?
What I need is to take 24 training examples from one of the classes and 8  examples from the other.
Probably, I should amend the flow_from_directory() function concerning the training data set in some way. Unfortunately, there is nothing connected to that in the keras documentation.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I can't say with 100% certainty but as far as I know, batch_size does not take an equal number of samples from all the labels rather it takes randomly. So if your data is unbalanced then the random sample will also be unbalanced.

Comment: Does that mean that I cannot guarantee that each training batch would have exactly  24 training examples from one of the classes and 8 examples from the other?

Comment: There might be some possible wary but I don't really know, however, if that data that you are fitting is unbalanced let's say the ratio of labels is 4:1, then I would imagine random sampling will approximately reflect that same ratio in batches of your data.